# Distinguish between folders and files in C++

Tags: c++

I have this code that opens a directory and checks if the list is not a regular file (means it's a folder) it will open it too. How can I distinguish between files and folders with C++.
here is my code if this helps :

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

// Pointer to a directory
DIR *pdir = NULL;
pdir = opendir(".");

struct dirent *pent = NULL;

if(pdir == NULL){
    cout<<" pdir wasn't initialized properly!";
    exit(8);
}

while (pent = readdir(pdir)){ // While there is still something to read
    if(pent == NULL){
    cout<<" pdir wasn't initialized properly!";
    exit(8);
}

    cout<< pent->d_name << endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use `stat` (or `lstat`) and `S_ISDIR`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be:

```
switch (pent->d_type) {
    case DT_REG:
        // Regular file
        break;
    case DT_DIR:
        // Directory
        break;
    default:
        // Unhandled by this example
}
```

You can see the `struct dirent` documentation on the [GNU C Library Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, another way would be:

```
    struct stat pent_stat;
    if (stat(pent->d_name, &pent_stat)) {
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(8);
    }
    const char *type = "special";
    if (pent_stat.st_mode & _S_IFREG)
        type = "regular";
    if (pent_stat.st_mode & _S_IFDIR)
        type = "a directory";
    cout << pent->d_name << " is " << type << endl;
```

You'd have to patch the filename with the original directory if it differs from `.`